# Get the current drive's volume label

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'd like to get the volume label of the current drive, and extract whatever is after `"-"`.

The idea is to use this as a variable in robocopy.

For example:

If the name of the volume label is `Potato - Watermelon and banana` it would only be `Watermelon and banana`

The idea is to use this as a variable in robocopy.

The robocopy script would look like this:

```
robocopy /e /zb /v /sec /copyall %~d0 "\\192.168.0.130\Backup\VARIABLE-WITH-TEXT-EXTRACTED-OF-VOLUME-LABEL" /xd "03. Proxy" /xf *.avi
```

Comment: Technically the name would begin with a space, i.e. ```<space>Watermelon<space>and<space>banana```, because that's what comes after the hyphen. So please think again what you're asking for, and correct your question by way of the [Edit] facility. Also your question asks about retrieving the volume label, which has already been answered before, and splitting a string at or after a particular character, which had also been answered before. Your question therefore shows a lack of effort, which I'd suggest you rectify, if you don't want to receive down/close votes.

Comment: [`label`](https://ss64.com/nt/label.html)…